# Do stuff when image has loaded

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to improve this script with a load function, so that the loading gif animation `$(".loader").show();` will be hidden with `$(".loader").hide();` when the image has been loaded. I have tried to use the `.load()` method, but then noting works! The important thing with this script is that it only affect the `.mainImage` within its article element of several article elements that also has a `.mainImage`.

Would it be possible to add `$(".loader").hide();` when the image has loaded?

```
$(".buttonContainer ul li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".loader").show();
    var btnUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).parents(".post").find(".mainImage").attr("src",btnUrl);
});
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded"); })
    .on('error', function() { console.log("error loading"); })
    .attr("src", $(original_Image).attr("src"))
;
```